# digital ocean sub domain settings not working

Tags: php, apache2, digital-ocean

I have a main domain and 2 subdomains.
1. www.hardyhawks.com
2. phabricator.hardyhawks.com
3. svn.hardyhawks.com

Main domain and phabricator.hardyhawks.com works fine but svn.hardyhawks.com ask after asking for credentials shows main domain in a distorted format. I have properly set the virtual host. Here is my zone file
`$TTL   1800
@       IN  SOA NS1.DIGITALOCEAN.COM.   hostmaster.hardyhawks.com. (
            1405689140 ; last update: 2014-07-18 13:12:20 UTC
            3600 ; refresh
            900 ; retry
            1209600 ; expire
            1800 ; ttl
            )
             IN      NS      NS1.DIGITALOCEAN.COM.
                     NS      NS2.DIGITALOCEAN.COM.
                     NS      NS3.DIGITALOCEAN.COM.
*   CNAME   @
phabricator IN A    my_ip
email   IN A    my_ip
svn IN A    my_ip
*.svn   CNAME   svn.hardyhawks.com.
@   IN A    my_ip
www CNAME   @`

Comment: Could you show your svn VirtualHost? Do you have an `.htacces` file in the svn root? If so, could you post that too?

Comment: And your config for virtual host svn?